# Regular Expression for an entire text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been working on a regular expression to divide the one text in sentences. But I been having problems with numbers like 13.4 or emails. In reasons of the '.'. Someone would how to fix it?

```
/([^\n\r\.!\?:;]+[\.!\?:;]\s)|([^\.!\?]+$)/g
```

Comment: Splitting texts into sentences is a complex NLP task. You might get some results with a single regex, but it won't be 100% safe to split any arbitrary text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @WiktorStribizew said, this is a too hard task to be completed with just regex. But you can still get an approximation matching interpunction followed by spaces or new lines:

```
/.*?[.!?:;](\s|[\r\n]|$)/gm
```

You can see an example [here](https://regex101.com/r/feY5Aq/2).

Comment: Thank you I understand in what @WiktorStribizew said I was trying to send it just in sentences for the backend. I've been studying machine learning algorithms to apply more to my projects. At the moment I'm working in a model to analyze phrases. That's actually why I was wanting to divide in sentences. I still training the model